# fine tune a model using Keras Functional API

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am using VGG16 to finetune it on my dataset.

Here's the model:

```
def finetune(self, aux_input):
        model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
        # return model

        drop_5 = Input(shape=(7, 7, 512))
        flatten = Flatten()(drop_5)
        # aux_input = Input(shape=(1,))
        concat = Concatenate(axis=1)([flatten, aux_input])

        fc1 = Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(self.weight_decay))(concat)
        fc1 = Activation('relu')(fc1)
        fc1 = BatchNormalization()(fc1)

        fc1_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc1)
        fc2 = Dense(self.num_classes)(fc1_drop)
        top_model_out = Activation('softmax')(fc2)

        top_model = Model(inputs=drop_5, outputs=top_model_out)

        output = top_model(model.output)

        complete_model = Model(inputs=[model.input, aux_input], outputs=output)

        return complete_model
```

I have two inputs to the model. In the above function, I'm using Concatenate for the flattened array and my aux_input. 
I'm not sure if this would work with imagenet weights.

When I run this, I get an error:

> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("aux_input:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "aux_input". The following previous layers were accessed without
>   issue: ['input_2', 'flatten_1']

Not sure where am I going wrong.

If it matters, this is fit function:

```
model.fit(x={'input_1': x_train, 'aux_input': y_aux_train}, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=maxepoches, validation_data=([x_test, y_aux_test], y_test),
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard], verbose=2)
```

But, I get an error before this `fit` function when I call `model.summary()`.

Comment: How do you call your `finetune` function?

Comment: It's in the class. so 
`ft = FModel() 
model = ft.finetune(aux_input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `aux_input` in your `top_model` but you don't specify it as an input in your definition of `top_model`. Try replacing your definition of `top_model` and `output` with the following:

```
top_model = Model(inputs=[drop_5, aux_input], outputs=top_model_out)
output = top_model([model.output, aux_input])
```

Comment: Now, got this error: `ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 512). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.`

Comment: This is because the VGG model doesn't have a fixed input shape so you cannot be sure that it matches your specified input shape `(7, 7, 512)` that the top model needs. You can fix this by adding `input_shape=(224, 224, 3)` as argument to the `applications.VGG16()` function.